# Orthogonalize in Python. Which package?

Tags: python, vector, linear-algebra

I need to orthogonalize vectors in Python. I have found so far only [algorithms.orthogonalize](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=algorithms.orthogonalize).

Nevertheless, it looks like "algorithms" is a kind of a package (module?) I cannot find to install. Has anybody done an orthogonalization? Please, advice me a nice package/module for this procedure. I am quite new in Python.

Comment: Thanks! I will install this...

Comment: Does [numpy.linalg.qr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) help?

Comment: hm...looks like it can be also done... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[numpy.linalg.qr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) turns out to be the best option to orthogonalize vectors, since the vectors I consider vectors with complex components. And if one does it with **the orthogonalize method** mentioned above, then one LOSES the complex parts!

Comment: In 2022 you can go with `scipy.linalg.orth`.

Answer (score 2):

That package is part of the [Spectral Python project](http://spectralpython.sourceforge.net/).

The [`orthogonalize` method is documented here](http://spectralpython.sourceforge.net/class_func_ref.html#orthogonalize):

> Performs Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization on a set of vectors

It is [installable via pip and easy_install](http://spectralpython.sourceforge.net/installation.html).

Comment: There are also dependencies for this, not really useful to have to install everything only for one function.